# Django admin disable foreign key drop down but keep add button next to it

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have a dropdown like so:

[image]

I want a particular foreign key to be disabled, but want the "plus" button intact. So that in admin a user can only add the value but cannot edit or select from the list.

I want kind of like **add_only**.

Comment: What was a solution for this? I have the similar task (add and edit, but not select from existing list).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue -- the dropdown for a related field had far too many values, causing the admin edit page to load incredibly slowly (and sometimes cause a timeout). But I still needed to be able to operate on the foreign key field.

You can both disable the dropdown and remove the edit button using the model form.

- Set the foreign key field to be disabled. This will prevent it from being populated, and prevent the user from manually selecting from the dropdown.
- Set the foreign key field's widget to `can_change_related = False`. This will remove the edit button.

The code would look like:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a_ref = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)

class ModelBAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['a_ref'].disabled = True
        self.fields['a_ref'].widget.can_change_related = False

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = '__all__'

class ModelBAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ModelBAdminForm
```

You can also disable the create button with `can_add_related = False`

And, you can reduce the size of the dropdown by refining the query with `self.fields['a_ref'].queryset = ModelB.obejcts.filter(...)`

Comment: Thanks for this. But, this doesn't seem to be working for django 1.8  and I cannot upgrade further. That would be big task.  My requirements also changed a bit. So thanks anyway

Comment: This does not allow to add new instance for related model. With disabling widget it doesn't save fk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's admin options to allow which model fields you can view/edit/delete: [ModelAdmin Options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

I believe you can use the list_editable field:

```
class MyModelAdmin(OrderedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo_editable', 'bar_editable', 'publisher')
    list_editable = ['foo_editable',  'bar_editable',]

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            # obj is not None, so this is an edit
            return ['publisher',] # Return a list or tuple of readonly fields' names
        else: 
            # This is an addition
            return []

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Sorry if my question was not clear.I want to make the feild non editable and non selectable. but admin should be able to add with "plus" symbol as in the pic.

Comment: Can you post your models.py code? See my change above

Comment: The readonly_feild option is working for me without any overhead. but,I want like "add only". If the field is a foriegn key it will show a drop down with plus next to it.I want to disable that drop down and plus button stay there so that admins can add,but cannot select from dropdown

Comment: Thank for the help.I end up using javascript way of disabling the select dropdown.Its kind of like a hack.Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @saiyan could you share your final hack solution, please?